# Postgres causing swapping on CentOS

Tags: postgresql, swap

All,

I am running CentOS 6.0 with Postgresql 8.4 and can't seem to figure out how to prevent so much disc swap from occurring. I have 12 gigs of RAM and 4 processors and I am doing some simple updates (1 table at a time). I thought for a minute that the inserts happening in parallel from a script I wrong was causing the large memory usage but when I saw the simple update causing it too I basically threw in the towel and decided to ask for help.

I pasted the conf file here. http://pastebin.com/e0jdBu0J

You can see that I set the buffers relatively low and the connection amounts high. The DB service will not start if I set the shared buffers any higher than 64 megs. Anyone have an idea what may be causing this for me?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Must be something with your CentOS configuration. Shared Buffers can easily be set to 512MB and 4GB is not unheard off. You should post the error message that you get if you go beyond 64MB

Comment: Here ya go...http://pastebin.com/FsyawN3S I followed the Postgresql recommended settings here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/kernel-resources.html but it still swaps.

Comment: Here is the my /etc/sysctl.conf file. http://pastebin.com/TUMcPequ

Comment: Can you provide evidence of your using swap excessively?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're going into swap, increasing shared_buffers will make the problem worse; you'll be taking RAM away from the part that's running out and swapping, instead dedicating memory to the database caching.  It's worth fixing SHMMAX etc. just on general principle and for later tuning work, but that's not going to help with this problem.

Guessing at the identify of your memory gobbling source is a crapshoot.  Far better to look at data from "top -c" and ps to find which processes are using a lot of it.  It's possible for a really bad query to consume way more memory than it should.  If you see memory use spike up for a PostgreSQL process running something, check the process ID against the information in pg_stat_tables to see what it's doing.

There are a couple of things that can cause this sort of issue that often surprise people.  If you are doing a large number of row updates in a single transaction, and there are foreign key checks or triggers involved, that can run out of memory.  The queue of things to check in each of those cases is kept in RAM, and can be surprisingly big.

There are two problems with your PostgreSQL settings that might be related.  Databases don't actually work very well if you have a lot more active connections than cores in the server; best performance is normally 2 to 3 active clients per core.  And all sorts of things go wrong once you've got more than a few hundred connection.  There is some connections^2 behavior that gets ugly there performance wise, and there are some memory issues too.  If you really need 1250 connections, you should be using a connection pooler such as pgBouncer or pgpool-II.

And effective_io_concurrency = 1000 is way too high for any hardware on the planet.  Useful values for that in a small multiple of how many disks you have in the server.  I have no idea what happens as far as memory usage goes when you set it that high, but it's not been tested very well at that range.  Normal settings more like 1 to 25.  The parameters outlined at [Tuning Your PostgreSQL Server](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) are much more important than it is; the concurrency value only impacts one particular type of table scan.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic writeup, sir! I used this as a starting point and obviously went overboard on the configuration. http://thesteve0.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/quick-note-on-tuning-postrgres/

Answer (score 1):

Centos 6 seems to have a very conservative shmmax as a default
Set your shared buffers to that recommended by [postgres tuning resources](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)

see [for explanation and how to set](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html).

To experiment you can (as root) use sysctl -w  kernel.shmmax = n
where n is the value that the startup error message that postgres is trying to allocate on startup. When you identify the value you wish to use permanently then set that in /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: Thanks Gavin! I bumped everything up to 4 gigs and am still experiencing a lot of swap on disc. I increased the shared buffer size to 2 gigs and the service did start but it did not fix the issue at hand.

Comment: Howe are you seeing/determining that swapping is going on ?

Comment: @nos I was looking at the swap happen in near real time using top -c